# Mindmap with tikz-picture//pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I am trying to set-up a mindmap with the subsequent layout:

[image: intended layout by mindmap]
However, I fail to arrange the node and its children. Here goes the MWE so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,arrows.meta,calc,mindmap,trees}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=blue]
\node[concept] {A} 
    [clockwise from= 300]
    child[concept color=green] {
        node[concept] {C}
        [clockwise from= 300]
        child { node[concept] {C1} }
        child { node[concept] {C2} }
    }
    child[concept color=green] 
    {node[concept] {B}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this suit your requirements?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap, 
    level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=90},
    level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=90},
    level 3 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60},
    concept color=blue!50,
]
\node[concept, font=\Huge] {A} 
    [counterclockwise from=225]
    child[concept color=green!60!blue!50] {
        node[concept, font=\normalsize] {B}
    }
    child[concept color=green!60!blue!50] {
        node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C} 
        [counterclockwise from=225]
        child { node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C1} 
        [counterclockwise from=240]
            child { node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C11} }
            child { node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C12} }
        }
        child {node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C2} 
        [counterclockwise from=240]
            child { node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C21} }
            child { node[concept, font=\normalsize] {C22} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great job, thank you!

Comment: How can I assure that font size is equal everywhere? What happens, if I have more text in those bubbles?

Comment: @Jens You can set the font size manually in each node with the ``font`` key. I modified my example to show it.

Answer (score 3):

My first attempt with mind maps

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                    mindmap,
                    concept color=blue
                    ] 
\node[concept] {a}
    [clockwise from=300]
        child [concept color=pink]{node[concept] {c}    
            child[concept color=teal!70!green] {node[concept] {c1}      
                child {node[concept] {c11}}
                child {node[concept] {c12}}}
            child[concept color=violet!75] {node[concept] {c2}
                child {node[concept] {c21}}
                child {node[concept] {c22}}}}
        child[concept color=orange!80] {node[concept] {b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```